# Selecting rows following a certain event and within a time difference

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I have trouble getting my code to work. I would like to get the next row after a certain value of `factor` in the previous row. But I would only want to save it if the distance in time is below a certain threshold, which i would like to test different variations.
Below is a sample data and my try with dplyr. But the result is not what I want.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# Setting up a data.frame
df_stackOverflow <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,
                                  2,2,2,2,
                                  3,3,
                                  4,4,
                                  5,5,5,
                                  6,6,6),
                           time = c("2016-11-11 10:25:07", "2016-11-11 11:13:09",
                                    "2016-11-16 21:13:28", "2016-11-29 19:18:58", "2016-12-01 18:44:41", "2016-12-04 12:46:44",
                                    "2016-12-26 20:49:07", "2016-12-30 11:41:51",
                                    "2016-11-25 10:25:52", "2016-12-26 22:04:36",
                                    "2016-12-07 21:27:53", "2016-12-07 21:52:58", "2016-12-09 18:32:23",
                                    "2016-11-25 14:10:24", "2016-11-25 20:06:43", "2016-11-25 21:07:33"),
                           Factor = c("A","B",
                                      "C","B","B","C",
                                      "B","B",
                                      "A","D",
                                      "D","D","D",
                                      "B","E","B"))

# My try to save a data.frame 
# I want to save all ros where the previous value for that ID was "B".
# And also the the time difference between this and the previous value need to be under a certain threshold.
# This threshold will be looped for different values
df_res <- list()
for(i in 1:15) {
  df_res[[i]] <- df_stackOverflow %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(lag(Factor) == "B" & as.period(interval(as.POSIXct(time), as.POSIXct(lag(time))), units = "day") < days(i))
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
lapply(1:5,function(x) df_stackOverflow %>% group_by(ID) %>%
                        mutate(differ = as.numeric(difftime(time,lag(time)),unit="days"),prev = lag(Factor)) %>%
                        filter(prev=="B" & differ < x))
```

Get the lag for factor and time by the grouped ID and Loop over whatever threshold you want via `lapply`. The results are stored in a list.

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I want :D
So if I would like to do intervals of 30 min, 1h, 12h, 1day... then I would have to change unit="minutes"... ?

Comment: `unit` in `difftime` changes the unit of time returned from the function. If you want to pass different thresholds, you can change the Input vector in the `lapply` function (1:5 in my example). You can change the input vector according to the unit of time selected. e.g. if you set `unit=minutes` and the Input vector to `c(30,60,60*12,60*24)` you would test for 30 min, 1h, 12h, 1day.